# android custom camera stretched surfaceview

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

i am facing a problem with the camera view i.e the view of camera is coming stretched and not giving a normal view like the default camera app or any other camera app gives.
I have been unable to get the surface view which the camera uses to stretch larger than the screen size.

```
 enter code here
  private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(); 
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder); 
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(getPreviewDegree(MainActivity.this));
            camera.startPreview(); // 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        setCameraParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
  private int getPreviewDegree(Activity activity) {
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degree = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degree = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degree = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degree = 270;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degree = 180;
            break;
    }
    return degree;
}

private void setCameraParameters() {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    List<Camera.Size> sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    if (sizeList.size() > 0) {
        Camera.Size cameraSize = sizeList.get(0);

        parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraSize.width, cameraSize.height);
    }


    sizeList = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
    if (sizeList.size() > 0) {
        Camera.Size cameraSize = sizeList.get(0);
        for (Camera.Size size : sizeList) {

            if (size.width * size.height < 10 * 100) {
                cameraSize = size;
                break;
            }
        }
        parameters.setPictureSize(cameraSize.width, cameraSize.height);
    }

    parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
    parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
    parameters.setJpegThumbnailQuality(100);

    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);

    startOrientationChangeListener();
}

private void startOrientationChangeListener() {

    OrientationEventListener mOrEventListener = new    OrientationEventListener(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int rotation) {

            if (((rotation >= 0) && (rotation <= 45)) || (rotation > 315)) {
                rotation = 0;
            } else if ((rotation > 45) && (rotation <= 135)) {
                rotation = 90;
            } else if ((rotation > 135) && (rotation <= 225)) {
                rotation = 180;
            } else if ((rotation > 225) && (rotation <= 315)) {
                rotation = 270;
            } else {
                rotation = 0;
            }
            if (rotation == mOrientation)
                return;
            mOrientation = rotation;
            updateCameraOrientation();
        }
    };
    mOrEventListener.enable();
}

 private void updateCameraOrientation() {
    if (camera != null) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        int rotation = 90 + mOrientation == 360 ? 0 : 90 + mOrientation;

        if (mIsFrontCamera) {
            if (rotation == 90) rotation = 270;
            else if (rotation == 270) rotation = 90;
        }
        parameters.setRotation(rotation);

        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can begin with this project .https://github.com/pikanji/CameraPreviewSample

Answer (score 0):

Try after add SurfaceHoler parmeters in surfaceCreated metod of SurfaceCallback class:

```
  holder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
  holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Hope its helps you.

Comment: You can refer below link for more detail.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545889/custom-camera-app-in-android-problems-rotation-270-stretched-capture-view-and